# Make mobile menu appear sooner on Magento 2

Tags: magento2

The mobile menu appears at 768px and I want to change that to a custom value.

I've read on here to do the following:

The JS for the menu that has that functionality can be found in

> lib/web/mage/menu.js

First create the folder structure in your theme ex:

> [Namespace]/[theme_name]/web/mage/

And copy menu.js from `lib/web/mage/menu.js` to `[Namespace]/[theme_name]/web/mage/menu.js`

And change

```
 mediaBreakpoint: '(max-width: 768px)'
```

to

```
mediaBreakpoint: '(max-width: 1025px)'
```

But this isn't working, can anyone help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override

> /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/js/navigation-menu.js

in your theme

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/web/js/navigation-menu.js

Change in line No. 400

```
media: '(min-width: 768px)',
```

**TO**

```
media: '(min-width: 1024px)',
```

---

Override

> /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/_navigation.less

in your theme

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/web/css/source/_navigation.less

Change in line No. 51

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break = @screen__m) {
```

**TO**

```
& when (@media-target = 'mobile'), (@media-target = 'all') {
@media all and (max-width: (@screen__l)) {
    // Your code here
}
}
```

Change in line No. 275

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
```

**TO**

```
& when (@media-target = 'desktop'), (@media-target = 'all') {
@media all and (min-width: (@screen__l)) {
    // Your code here
}
}
```

Comment: That's awesome thanks so much! On mobile a search icon appears that toggles the search box. Do you know how to make that appear sooner with the rest of the mobile  menu please?

Comment: Sure, will check for search toggle and post here. if this answer works for you can you please accept and vote. :)

Answer (score 1):

**YOUR SECOND QUESTION :**

On mobile a search icon appears that toggles the search box. Do you know how to make that appear sooner with the rest of the mobile menu.

**MY ANSWER :**

Override :

> /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_CatalogSearch/web/css/source/_module.less

in your theme :

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_CatalogSearch/web/css/source/_module.less

***Old CSS :***

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
.block-search {
    float: right;
    padding-left: 15px;
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 4;

    .label {
        &:extend(.abs-visually-hidden-desktop all);
    }

    .control {
        border-top: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    input {
        .lib-input-placeholder(@form-element-input-placeholder__color);
        margin: 0;
        padding-right: 35px;
        position: static;
    }

    .action.search {
        display: inline-block;
        .lib-button-icon(
        @_icon-font-content: @icon-search,
        @_icon-font-size: 16px,
        @_icon-font-text-hide: true,
        @_icon-font-color: @header-icons-color,
        @_icon-font-color-hover: @header-icons-color-hover,
        @_icon-font-line-height: 32px
        );
        .lib-button-reset();
        position: absolute;
        right: @indent__s;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1;

        &:focus {
            &:before {
                .lib-css(color, @color-gray20);
            }
        }
    }
}

.search-autocomplete {
    margin-top: 0;
}
}
```

***Replace below CSS with Old CSS:***

```
& when (@media-target = 'desktop'), (@media-target = 'all') {
@media all and (min-width: (@screen__l)) {
    .block-search {
        float: right;
        padding-left: 15px;
        position: relative;
        width: 250px;
        z-index: 4;

        .label {
            border: 0;
            clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
            height: 1px;
            margin: -1px;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 0;
            position: absolute;
            width: 1px;
        }

        .control {
            border-top: 0;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        input {
            .lib-input-placeholder(@form-element-input-placeholder__color);
            margin: 0;
            padding-right: 35px;
            position: static;
        }

        .action.search {
            display: inline-block;
            .lib-button-icon(
                @_icon-font-content: @icon-search,
                @_icon-font-size: 16px,
                @_icon-font-text-hide: true,
                @_icon-font-color: @header-icons-color,
                @_icon-font-color-hover: @header-icons-color-hover,
                @_icon-font-line-height: 32px
            );
            .lib-button-reset();
            position: absolute;
            right: @indent__s;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 1;

            &:focus {
                &:before {
                    .lib-css(color, @color-gray20);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    .search-autocomplete {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome anytime. If search toggle works for you can you please vote and accept so another person use the same

Comment: Yep it worked, just voted this answer for you now :)